# How to fix this bug when running Azure CLI to create Alerting on Application Insight on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-cli

I use "az monitor scheduled-query" to create ALerting on Application Insight on Azure but it show me error message "ERROR: (BadRequest) Scope can not be updated"
. Please help me to fix this bug

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have run the command to create the alert rule in Application Insights for Azure VM with the below command:

```
az monitor scheduled-query create -g "HariTestRG" -n "testkvm01" --scopes "/subscriptions/<subs-id>/resourceGroups/<RGName>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/testkvm01" --condition "count 'Placeholder_1' > 360 resource id _ResourceId at least 1 violations out of 5 aggregated points" --condition-query Placeholder_1="union Event, Syslog | where TimeGenerated > ago(1h) | where EventLevelName=='Error' or SeverityLevel=='err'" --description "Test rule"
```

Here vm_id is the resource id of the virtual machine.

**Result**:
[image]

[image]

**In Portal View**:
[image]

**References**: [MSFT Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/scheduled-query?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-scheduled-query-create) of CLI command to create the Scheduled Alert

Answer (score 0):

i got the same error and i got a better view of the error when i went to
Azure Portal > Resource Group > (see image below)

1. Activity Log
2. Create Deployment
3. Scheduled query rule write (The specific line that failed)
4. JSON

[image: view BadRequest error]

The cause of error for me was that an existing alert rule already exists for another Azure Data Factory. so i renamed the Alert Rule names and got it fixed.